# how to add Images and add constraints in TableCell programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, snapkit

I want to achieve the effect of the picture below. **I wanted to add images(which have been framed by me with red lines) in my cell**, and how to achieve this?
I try to do some layout by using `equalToSuperView().inset(10)`**, but I didn't know how to set relationship between the cell and the image.：**

[image]

1. I created a `WechatMomentListCell` which follow the protocol `UITableViewCell`

```
class WechatMomentListCell: UITableViewCell{
    var content = UILabel()
    var senderAvatar = UIImageView()
    var senderNick = UILabel()
    var Images = [UIImageView()]
    var comments = [UILabel()]
}
```

2. I try to implements func `tableView()` in my `ViewController` like this, here is the part of layouting avatar.

```
tweetCell.senderAvatar.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: tweet?.sender?.avatar ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
//tweetCell.senderAvatar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 40, height: 40)

tweetCell.senderAvatar.snp.makeConstraints{(make) in
    make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(50)
    make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
    make.width.equalTo(40)
    make.height.equalTo(40)
}
```

3. Here is the whole code of override `tableView`:

```
let tweet = viewModel.tweetList?[indexPath.row]

for i in tweet?.images ?? [] {
    let flagImage = UIImageView()
    flagImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: i.url))
    tweetCell.Images.append(flagImage)
}
for i in tweet?.comments ?? [] {
    let flagComment = UILabel()
    flagComment.text = "\(i.sender) : \(i.content)"
    tweetCell.comments.append(flagComment)
}
tweetCell.senderNick.text = tweet?.sender?.nick
tweetCell.senderAvatar.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: tweet?.sender?.avatar ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))

//this part use for layouting avatar
tweetCell.senderAvatar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 40, height: 40)
tweetCell.senderAvatar.snp.makeConstraints{(make) in
    make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(50)
    make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
    make.width.equalTo(40)
    make.height.equalTo(40)
}        
return tweetCell
```

In my own demo, the table list cell shows blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is all the code in 1. your whole code for the cell?
If the cell is empty, I would first check if you have registered the cell to your tableView correctly and if the `cellForRow` delegate function actually returns the correct cell.

**Assuming that what is in 1. is your whole code for your cell:**
Your cell should handle much more of it's own setup. It should layout itself, download images itself and set it's constraints (programmatically, as you mentioned in your question). It is not really possible to correct your code with the snippets you provide. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pu7B7uEzP18) might be a good tutorial for you.

Comment: yes this video is really helpful!  Thanks a lot!